# .save() method of Mongoose behaving unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, mongoose, supertest

I'm creating an API that stores users, allows users to login, read their profile etc on the basis of the username and password.

The routes are all successfully built but during the testing of the api using 'Supertest' library, I'm finding some issue.

> **I tried creating a user instance userOne as follows (Before calling beforeEach method) :**

```
//Creating a mock user for testing
const userOneId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
const userOne = new User({
    _id: userOneId,
    name: 'Temp-user',
    email: 'tempuser@gmail.com',
    password: 'tempuser',
    age:40,
    tokens: [{
        token: jwt.sign({_id:userOneId},process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    }]
})
 
beforeEach(async ()=>{
    try{
    await User.deleteMany()
    await userOne.save()
    }catch(e){
        console.log('BeforeEach error: ',e)
    }
```

> This made my test fail with beforeEach throwing the following Error:

```
  BeforeEach error:  DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5f2570846592c22d641e3247 }" on model "User"
        at /home/priyank_linux/Desktop/node-course/task-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:323:38
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
      result: undefined,
      numAffected: undefined,
      filter: { _id: 5f2570846592c22d641e3247 },
      query: { _id: 5f2570846592c22d641e3247 }
    }
```

*> However, when I tried the following approach of saving the user before each test, all of my tests passed*

```
//Creating a mock user for testing
const userOneId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
const userOne = {
    _id: userOneId,
    name: 'Temp-user',
    email: 'tempuser@gmail.com',
    password: 'tempuser',
    age:40,
    tokens: [{
        token: jwt.sign({_id:userOneId},process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    }]
}
 
beforeEach(async ()=>{
    try{
    await  User.deleteMany()
     //creating and saving the user instance at the same time
    await new User(userOne).save()    
    }catch(e){
        console.log('BeforeEach error: ',e)
    }
    
})
 
//All tests passed successfully !
```

---

**My question is, why is it that when I create and save an instance of
User model at the same time, I'm not getting the Document not found
error (which implies that the saved document is actually getting
stored in the database).  Where am I going wrong ?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I received from Udemy and I believe it is 100% accurate:

*Since you're only creating a single document in the first example, it looks like Mongoose is trying to update the existing document for all save calls after the first one. The problem is that it's deleted though. So the local document thinks it's been saved, but the save version was deleted behind the scenes.*